# How to prevent the messages about REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED

Tags: linux, ssh, security

Is it possible to prevent the following message about: ( REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED )

When using only this connection syntax

```
 ssh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

example of warning message:

```
 ssh  10.19.11.1
 CentOS release 5.8 (Final)
 Kernel 2.6.18-308.el5 on an i686
 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
 @ WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED! @
 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
 IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
 Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
 It is also possible that the RSA host key has just been changed.
 The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
 dd:6f:32:8f:8f:8c:70:9c:95:f1:48:83:60:97:cc:ed.
 Please contact your system administrator.
 Add correct host key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
 Offending key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:7
 RSA host key for 10.19.11.1 has changed and you have requested strict checkin.
 Host key verification failed.
```

each time I get these message , then I clean the /root/.ssh/known_hosts

as

```
     cp /dev/null /root/.ssh/known_hosts
```

I also was thinking to set the command cp /dev/null /root/.ssh/known_hosts
in the crontab ,

so every day at 24:00 it clean the known_hosts file ( this solution decrease this problem but not solved it )

so  this solution isn’t so good solution because user can get the warning message in spite we clean the known_hosts file evry day

maybe we can do something on /etc/ssh/ssh_config file in order to prevent the SSH host key checking?

remark:

I don’t want to use the following method in order to prevent the SSH host key checking ( because I use reflection/putty )

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no peter@192.168.0.100
```

I am insist to use only this syntax as

```
 ssh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

for connection

Comment: Simply put: don't do it. **Did you actually read that warning at all?** There is a reason for this warning. And it is to protect you from harm of a MitM attack and other bad things.

Comment: @0xC0000022L
Is it the same risky if you try to login to (a docker contaier) at 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @Kuchara I'd say it still depends, but the risk is of course limited. If you can trust this container, e.g. because you yourself built the image, then this could work. However, in that case you may want (and are able) to "discover" the public host key by different means and therefore don't have to trust _any_ value either. But the risk seems reduced in this scenario, I agree.

Comment: @0xC0000022L My concern is if there is an option to spoof 127.0.0.1 IP address somehow? But I've just found this option that works flawlessly for 127.0.0.1: `NoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost=yes`

Comment: @Kuchara I think spoofing is of little concern in this case. These address ranges (it's not _just_ 127.0.0.1) receive special treatment.

Answer (score 7):

When connecting to throwaway virtual machines or such, you should better not store the keys in the first place.

Create a `ssh0` alias or function with the following content:

```
alias ssh0='ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o LogLevel=ERROR'
```

In this way, you won't pollute your `~/.known_hosts` file with garbage, and since you're using a different command, there would be a psychological boundary between the "real" ssh and the one used to instrument some local widget.

Another useful alias is

```
alias sshy='ssh -o CheckHostIP=no'
```

for when you're connecting to a device which changes its IP frequently, as eg. a home router to which the ISP assigns a different IP each time it's power-cycled.

Comment: Perfect answer to this!

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** Nowadays you can use [SSH certificates](https://gravitational.com/blog/how-to-ssh-properly/), similar to TLS certificates. Then you can add a `known_hosts` entry to trust the *certificate* rather than the individual keys, and you'll never get this message again.

---

Heed [@0xC0000022L's warning](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183943/how-to-prevent-the-messages-about-remote-host-identification-has-changed#comment306563_183943)!

If you *know* the host key has changed, you can remove that specific entry from the `known_hosts` file:

```
ssh-keygen -R xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

This is much better than overwriting the full hosts file (which can be done with just `> /root/.ssh/known_hosts`).

If you don't want to use `ssh` command-line options, I believe the only other way to do this would be to modify the SSH code and recompile. Which you **really** don't want to do!

Comment: but I want to do this by automatic way , when user complain about this , I don’t want to do it manual

Comment: You don't want to do it manually (removing `known_hosts` entries), and you don't want to do it automatically (using `ssh` options). How do you want to do it then?

Comment: @l0b0 By giving a command-line option to suppress the feature. In some environments, such as virtual machine environments and other very dynamic configurations (especially test environments), these host keys change frequently and because they are on an isolated network, there is little security to gain by doing the check. Having to do an `ssh-keygen -R` every time is annoying. I suppose one could write a shell for ssh, a shell script that parses the destination address and pre-removes the key before passing options to ssh, but this seems like overkill.

Answer (score 2):

step 1 : remove faulty key

```
 ssh-keygen -R 192.168.1.1
```

step 2 : add new key

```
 ssh-keyscan 192.168.1.1 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

or depending on your situation

```
 > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
ssh-keyscan 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 ... >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: -1 for providing a footgun without a warning.

Comment: @l0b0 Fair enough your honor !

Answer (score 2):

If only for connecting to 127.0.0.1 (localhost) matters, then this ssh option should work:

```
-o NoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost=yes
```

This option has existed since at least OpenSSH 3.7 (from 2003).